# Create MS Word Insert Table like behaviour with WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, styles

I am trying to get the same behaviour as in MS Word when inserting a table. When I move over a grid of rectangles, I want the rectangles to become blue displaying how many columns and rows the table should have.

I adapted an example I found, but I am getting stuck when I want all the rectangles to the left and above the current rectangle to change the Fill.

In my ViewModel I create a collection of 8 items:

```
ObservableCollection<BoardTileViewModel> board = new ObservableCollection<BoardTileViewModel>();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    board.Add(new BoardTileViewModel(this, i % 4, i / 4));
}
this.Board = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<BoardTileViewModel>(board);
```

As you can see, the BoardTileViewModel gets X/Y-coordinates via the constructor, so something could be done with that.
And I use the following style for a ItemsControl:

```
<ResourceDictionary
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="TileButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 1 1" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Rectangle" Fill="White" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_Rectangle" Property="Fill" Value="RoyalBlue" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="BoardItemsControlStyle" TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="124" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="62" />
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource TileButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding Check}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to set the Fill of all the rectangles left of and above the rectangle where the mouse is over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to succeed!

If someone wants to know the solution, this is what I did:

1. I have moved the styles from the resourcedictionary to the Window (to be able to add a MouseEnter-event).
2. I implemented an INotifyPropertyChanged in the BoardTileViewModel and added a Fill property. I bound the Fill property to the Fill of the Rectangle.
3. In the MouseEnter-event I get for the other rectangles and set their Fill property.

This made the Trigger useless, so I removed it from the ControlTemplate.